# How to draw blurred line on an image with Python?

Tags: python, pyqt, drawing

I need to generate a few thousands of JPEG images with straight lines of different colors, widths, slopes and brush forms and hardnesses. It should be done to test an image processing library. I want to do it via a Python script.

Alas, I don't know how to draw such a line in Python. AFAIK, PyQt can draw lines only with QPen (that does not support blurring), not with QBrush. Maybe there is another way to do it?

P.S. Here is an example test image. I made it with GIMP, but need to do it automatically with a script.

[image: Example]

Comment: It's hurting my eyes! (the line) On a separate note, please show some code.

Comment: I made the example manually, in GIMP. If I had the code that can draw such lines, I would not ask it here. ^__^